Gather data from NVMe
Recently my computer's CPU got damaged, hence, I can't use my laptop anymore. Therefore, I need to recover some data from the NVMe SSD which was in that laptop. On my NVMe SSD, I was dual booting Windows and Ubuntu 22.04. Therefore, I need to recover some data from the Ubuntu partition. How can I do this?
If someone could suggest an idea other than replacing this NVMe SSD in someone else's laptop, it would be very grateful.
Some details of the NVMe SSD are below:
SK Hynix NVME
PCIe Gen 3 X 4
512GB
LEN P/N: SSS0V27609
FRU: 5SS0V27611

Also, my Ubuntu partition is ext4. Don't know if this is helpful or not.
I don't know what other details one would require to solve this, so ask questions in the comments.

If you can't boot the system, even with a live USB, you will have to remove the nvme and use a nvme-to-USB adapter to copy the data off. If you can boot with a live USB, the solution is obvious.

@OrganicMarble , thanks. Will that be able to read the Ubuntu partition if I plugged it in someone else's windows  computer. Or will I have to plu it into someone else's Ubuntu to read the ext4 ubuntu partition?

It's been too long since I used Windows to know the answer to that. you could always boot their PC to an Ubuntu USB.

You almost certainly won’t access any Ubuntu data from Windows (ext 3/4 isn’t recognised by windows at all). Your best option is to get a usb-c caddy to turn that ssd into an external drive, plug it into a usb port on a computer, and use a live Ubuntu USB session in that computer to access your data on the ssd and copy it (probably to the host computer’s hard drive, though you could use another usb drive if enough ports). Then format your old ssd to something that works cross-platform, eg ntfs or fat, and you now have a large external hard drive that will be fast.

Windows(tm) does NOT support ext4 filesystems. At best, Windows will not see your data, at worst, it will attempt to "fix" the disk, to everyone's great sorrow.
